# Using Having statement and In Statement together

Tags: sql, group-by, having, oracle12c

Here is my hypothetical table, (lets call it Table Watched)

```
MovieID, UserID, Date
---------------------
1        1       June
1        2       June
2        3       July
2        2       August
3        1       August
3        2       August
4        1       August
```

I want to get all movies only watched by users 1 or 2. So, in this case, the result should be:

```
MovieID
--------
1
3
4
```

So, I was thinking to write a query like,

```
SELECT MovieID FROM Watched GROUP BY MovieID HAVING ALL UserID in (1,2)
```

It does not work. I am not sure is there another working query with the same way I am thinking now. I am thinking like the following,

1. Group all records with the MovieID
2. Eliminate the groups which has another user than 1 or 2

What should be the right way of doing this?

PS: I am using Oracle Database 12c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eliminate the groups which has another user than 1 or 2

You are on the right track, but you don't need `GROUP BY` - you can use `DISTINCT` instead. To get the results you're looking for you can use `NOT IN` instead of `HAVING`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    MovieID 
FROM Watched 
WHERE MovieID NOT IN
( SELECT MovieID FROM Watches
WHERE UserID NOT IN (1,2))
```